# What is the density of integers which can be written as the sum of two positive integer powers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, riemann-zeta

The power-free natural (asymptotic) density of $x^k$ is $1/\zeta(k)$ plus error terms.

I suppose this means that the number of integers less than $N$ that a have $k$ power in their factorization is:

$N(1-1/\zeta(k))$ plus error terms.

So, what is the asymptotic density of $x^k+y^l$?

Comment: The density of integers which are not divisible by $a^k$ for some $k > 1$ is $1/\zeta(k)$. The density of numbers of the form $a^k$ for $k > 1$ is $0$. The density of numbers of the form $a^k + b^l$ for $k,l \ge 2$ is also zero. There is a stupid bound when at least one of $k$ or $l$ is $3$, since then one can just count the number of pairs with $a^k \le x$ and $b^l \le x$; since $l,k \ll \log(x)$, this gives a bound of the form $O(x^{5/6} \log(x)^2)$. This leaves the case $k = l = 2$. The numbers which are sums of two squares grow like $Kx/\sqrt{\log(x)}$ for some specific constant $K$.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but a trivial lower bound. Too long to be a comment.

Let $f(x)$ be the number of positive integers $\le x$ which can be expressed as the sum of two powers. Then,

$f(x) > $ number of positive integers $\le x$ which can be expressed as the sum of two squares

or $f(x) > $ number of primes $\le x$ which can be expressed as the sum of two squares

or $f(x) > $  number of primes $\le x$ which are of the form $4k+1$.

Hence by Dirichlet theorem of primes in arithmetic progression,

$$
f(x) > \frac{x}{2\log x}.
$$